# Alter table query not updating my table

Tags: java, android

How to add column in an existing table? I used the following code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.rawQuery("ALTER TABLE " + MNEMONICTABLE +" ADD COLUMN " + F_STATUS +" int DEFAULT 0", null);
```

This code runs without error. But the new column was not added to the table.

Comment: You also need to upgrade your database version then only it will reflect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `rawQuery` instead of `execSQL`. Try this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + MNEMONICTABLE +" ADD COLUMN " + F_STATUS +" int DEFAULT 0");
```

Comment: I had following error. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1642)

Comment: @Govin just use the parameterless overload of `execSQL()` by removing the `, null`

Comment: you can do it with rawQuery also, you just need to commit the transaction. Usually `cursor.moveToFirst()` or some of these

Comment: An `ALTER TABLE` SQL Statement is NO query! `rawQuery` is for SELECT statements ONLY, where execSQL is for anything EXCEPT `SELECT` statements! See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @mihail Nothing to do with transactions. `rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not run it. It needs one of the `moveTo...()` methods on the cursor to run it. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs.

Comment: @RafaelT The docs are bad. Some clarification e.g. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110274/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-inserts-updates-deletes-in-android-sqlitedatabase/20118910#20118910

Comment: @laalto, you are right, anyway, my point was that you can use rawQuery, you just have to call some of the moveTo... methods to complete it.

Comment: And WHY should one use the somehow wrong method and call another method just to make the 'hack' working, when there is a one-liner that will work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ALTER TABLE` function on your `onUpgrade()` method, like this :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    // If you need to add a column
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + MNEMONICTABLE +" ADD COLUMN " + F_STATUS +" int DEFAULT 0", null);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the SQLite will differ depending on the column definition. Also you need to upgrade your database version.

Answer (score -1):

you should **COMMIT** changes also

Comment: @harsh it can be turned off