# Can't get any data back from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote this simple Activity to test writing and reading from an SQLite database on Android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "TestDatabase", null, 3);
            getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Apple')", null);
            Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable", null);
            Log.d("trace", String.valueOf(cursor.moveToFirst()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TestTable (value text)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

}
```

The meat of it is in the DatabaseHelper constructor, where I write a value to TestTable, try to get it back in a cursor, and then log the value of cursor.moveToFirst() (which should only be `false` if the cursor is empty). It's `false`. What's going on?

Comment: Don't do stuff like that in constructor. Declare one method to write data and another to read data.

Comment: @ramaral It's just a test program. Or is there another reason?

Comment: I was able to get it working by writing with .insert rather than .rawQuery, but I have no idea why .rawQuery doesnt' work.

Comment: **"but I have no idea why .rawQuery doesnt' work."** Because it's a method to perform queries and not to do other SQL stuff (such as insert, delete etc etc) - the name kind of gives it away.

Comment: You can use [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) to execute non-query statements.

Comment: I think rawQuery should be used only with sql statemens that returns data. You should call execSQL instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

> [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29)  runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

Since then, you should not use it for `INSERT`. Try [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) or [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) for getting the row id of the inserted row.

Comment: Could the documentation possibly be any more vague? Forgive me for assuming "raw" meant *raw*. Thank you.

Comment: You are almost right, but consider query (in `rawQuery`) as a **query**. :)

Comment: Well, I've always thought of "query" as the general term for any SQL command.

Comment: @JackM For an answer involving query/exec distinction and Android sqlite documentation quirks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110274/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-inserts-updates-deletes-in-android-sqlitedatabase/20118910#20118910

Answer (score 0):

1) rawQuery() should be changed to execSQL like following line:

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "TestDatabase", null, 3);

        getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Apple')");
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable", null);
        Log.d("trace:", String.valueOf(cursor.moveToFirst()));
    }
```

2) in order to make sure call onCreate(), override onDowngrade() in your DatabaseHelper class:

```
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```