# How to update my string value into database

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Have a database with table name `status` and column name is `column1`. I need to update this.

I have a String value in `Activity1`

```
String check = "value";
```

I have passed this value into my `DBHelper`.I have tried like this

```
dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
dbhelper.sample(check);
```

I got this value in `DBHelpe`r.here. Like this

```
public void sample(String prms){
Log.d("sucess",prms);
}
```

Now how i need to update `String prms` into my database columnname `column1`

I have tried like this

```
public  void sample( String prms) {
        Log.d("DBHELPER SUCCESS", prms);

        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
            db1.execSQL("update appstatus SET status = '"+prms+"' WHERE id = 1 ");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("GET SAMPLE VALUE"+e);
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with my syntax? How to achieve this?

It shows exception as

```
02-28 12:09:45.604: I/System.out(4975): GET SAMPLE VALUEandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table report already exists (code 1): , while compiling: create table report(level TEXT, topic TEXT,  start TEXT, end TEXT, date TEXT)
```

Comment: You forget to add `Table Name` in your Query

Comment: status is my table name

Comment: any of your query doesn't work for me. it shows Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Comment: @MakeitSimple Are you the OP? Based on your comments you behave like you are. Please use only one account so that you don't get flagged for  sockpuppet upvoting or such.

Comment: @laalto Exactly all the user provides right answer with right suggestion over here.

Comment: @laalto i have tried its not working when i pass the value to that method in dbhelper that time app closes..

Comment: @MD  i have tried its not working when i pass the value to that method in dbhelper that time app closes..

Comment: That's a separate issue. Please post exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: @BalamuruganRadhakrishnan this issue is not about the Query LOL post your logcat for better understating

Comment: @laalto i didn't get any exception in logcat

Comment: @laalto I got null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

`rawQuery()` doesn't actually run the SQL. Use `execSQL()` instead:

```
db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ");
```

(See [What is the correct way to do inserts/updates/deletes in Android SQLiteDatabase using a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110274/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-inserts-updates-deletes-in-android-sqlitedatabase/20118910#20118910) to learn more how `rawQuery()` and `execSQL()` work under the hood.)

Comment: Doesn't work.. shows.. Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Comment: `execSQL()` does not return a `Cursor` so you cannot assign the return value to a cursor.

Comment: it shows Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Comment: Just remove the `Cursor cursor =`

Answer (score 2):

You can Directly `Execute` this Query like:

```
db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ", null);
```

You should replace your code

```
Cursor cursor = db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ", null);
```

With

```
db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ", null);
```

**void execSQL(String sql)**

Execute a single **SQL** statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other **SQL** statement that returns data.

It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use **insert(String, String, ContentValues**, **update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])**, et al, when possible.

Comment: it shows Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Answer (score 1):

db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ", null);

Comment: Doesn't work.. shows.. Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Answer (score 1):

Update your following line code,

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' ", null);
```

to this line

```
db.execSQL( "update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"' " );
```

So your method will look like this,

```
public void sample(String prms)
{ 
    Log.d("sucess",prms); 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"'WHERE id = '5' " );   // remove second param from here.
}
```

Caution : This query is going to update all the row of Column1; You should include `where` clause

Comment: i tried it shows Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Cursor

Comment: I have tried that query,.. its not updating. apps closes the value is passed to that method..

Comment: @BalamuruganRadhakrishnan what does this line `Log.d("sucess",prms);` prints on DDMS ?

Comment: can you again paste the code of sample() method , here in comment ?

Comment: public void sample(String prms){
Log.d("sucess",prms);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("update status SET column1 = '"+prms+"'WHERE id = '5' ", null);
}

Comment: @BalamuruganRadhakrishnan why you are passing second parameter `null` ? see my answer.

Comment: yes I given like that, it didn't update. in exception throws some other table name

Comment: @BalamuruganRadhakrishnan, this is a new error. I guess it is coming from other lines.

Comment: yes its coming from some where else. I don't know why its coming.. I have print exception here in that method..

Comment: Then without the code how can I saw anything about it ?

Comment: @BalamuruganRadhakrishnan there is no problem in this code. Since this is new problem I would like to suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: I didn't get solution @Kedarnath

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code,it return no. of rows effected while updating.

```
SQLiteHelper helper;
public int updateName(String oldName,String newName)
{
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(this.NAME, newName);
String [] whereArgs={oldName};

int count = db.update(helper.TABLE_NAME, values, helper.NAME+" =? ",whereArgs);
 return count;
 }
```

where helper is an object of class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` like the code below..

```
static class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
 ....////
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLENAME";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String UID = "_id";
 private static final String NAME = "Name";
 private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +"(" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(255));";

 public SQLiteHelper(Context context) 
 {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    Message.Message(context, "Constructor Called");


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    try {
        Message.Message(context, "OnCreate Called");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Message.Message(context, "" + e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Message.Message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Message.Message(context, ""+e);
    }

}
      }
```