# Why cursorObject.moveToFirst() is required on updating my database table value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I had a problem with updating of a column's value at a particular row. I had written

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+book+" SET footnotes='" + note + "' WHERE chapter="+chapter+" and verse="+verse+"", null);
c.close();
```

But on adding c.moveToFirst() it worked. Why is that?

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+book+" SET footnotes='" + note + "' WHERE chapter="+chapter+" and verse="+verse+"", null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

Why is c.moveToFirst() necessary here, any particular reason?

There is an explation for c.moveToFirst()
([What is The use of moveToFirst () in SQLite Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445010/what-is-the-use-of-movetofirst-in-sqlite-cursors)) which briefly suggests that using c.moveToFirst() does two things

> > allows you to test whether the query returned an empty set
> >
> > moves the cursor to the first result

But how does the above two things help in updation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The use of moveToFirst () in SQLite Cursors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445010/what-is-the-use-of-movetofirst-in-sqlite-cursors)

Answer (score 0):

Think of `rawQuery()` as a wrapper for the C library [`sqlite3_prepare_v2()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) that compiles the SQL but does not run it, while think of `moveTo..()` as a wrapper for [`sqlite3_step()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) that is required for actually executing the prepared statement.

Related: [What is the correct way to do inserts/updates/deletes in Android SQLiteDatabase using a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110274/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-inserts-updates-deletes-in-android-sqlitedatabase/20118910#20118910)

Comment: more or less: `moveTo..()` is not a wrapper for anything, it just makes `onMove()` to be called which is implemented by `SQLiteCursor` and does the real stuff