# UPDATE Query not Working with Android App

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an Android app that needs to execute an `UPDATE` query on a SQLite database, but for some reason, the query is not having any effect when I run it.

Here's the function that is supposed to execute the query.

```
public void query()
{
    try
    {
        cursor = this.db.rawQuery("UPDATE data SET saved=1 WHERE number=1", null);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Database Query Failed: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Although the query does not work, I do not get any output from the `catch` clause, and adding an additional `catch` to check for `Exception` does not output anything either.

What's the problem? How can I get `UPDATE` queries to work? I have not tried executing an `INSERT` query, but I will need to do that as well later on. Will I have similar issues with all queries that write to the database?

Comment: [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) has methods for insert, update, delete, etc. I suggest you explore the javadoc for that class.

Answer (score 2):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` to run the SQL.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not run it. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use `execSQL()` for `SELECT` queries as well, or do I still need to use `rawQuery()` for that?

Comment: "rawQuery() just compiles the SQL but does not run it." -- could you provide a reference for this? Official documentation says that it runs the query. However, it's undocumented what happens when you submit a query that returns no cursor.

Comment: @DavidB For `SELECT`s use `rawQuery()`. When you move the returned `Cursor` the SQL program is run until next result row.

Comment: @laalto Okay. Just wanted to see if I could use just one or another.

Comment: @323go It's basically the sqlite C API design - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110274/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-inserts-updates-deletes-in-android-sqlitedatabase/20118910#20118910

Answer (score 1):

`rawQuery()` is to return a cursor. An `UPDATE` statement does not return a cursor. Use `execSQL()` instead:

```
public void query() {
    try {
        this.db.execSQL("UPDATE data SET saved=1 WHERE number=1", null);
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database Query Failed: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

It would be wiser to use parameter substitution, instead of including your parameters in the query string, as follows:

```
public void query( int savedState, int number ) {
    try {
        Object[] params = new Object[]{ new Integer(savedState), new Integer(number) };

        this.db.execSQL("UPDATE data SET saved=? WHERE number=?", params );
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database Query Failed: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do parameter substitution?

Comment: See included sample. And thanks for the edit -- I copied/pasted ;)

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is this method recommended because it sanitizes input or is it a matter of convention?

Comment: In your specific case, it's not necessary, but it would be once one or both of your parameters become, well, parametric. It aids the readability of the query, and in case of string-parameters, it guards against SQL injection.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering if it has something to do with sanitation of input.